# Apache HTTP Client: NoHttpResponseException Exception not caught?

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I want to get the total number of retry times for sending requests if `NoHttpResponseException` is caught. I tried to implement the behavior with try-catch block and had a weird behavior:

1. Before I implemented this behavior, the exception is thrown and the program breaks.
2. After I implemented this behavior, the exception is not thrown anymore, and  the program run normally. However, it seems the codes in the `catch` part is not really executed:

```
        int retry = 0;
        final int MAX_RETRY = 1000;
        String response = null;
        JsonObject responseInJson = null;       
        while(true) {
            try {
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
                break;
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                if(exception instanceof NoHttpResponseException) {
                    retry++;
                    System.out.println("Retry for the " +  retry + " time(s)");
                    if(retry == MAX_RETRY) {
                        throw exception;
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Another exception occured");
                    throw exception;
                }   
            } 
        }
```

My class has an attribute:
`protected CloseableHttpClient httpClient;`

The attribute is initialized in the constructor:

```
    public AbstractData() {
        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(28800000)
                .setConnectTimeout(28800000)
                .setSocketTimeout(28800000)
                .build();
        this.httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .setMaxConnPerRoute(4)
                .setMaxConnTotal(4)
                .build();
    }
```

My question is, is there any logical error in the way I implement the behavior in the try-catch block? And is there any better way to alter directly the `DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler` to do this behavior (I tried to look up and did not find an example to check how many retry attempts the request is sent).

Comment: do you get "Another exception occured" in output?

Comment: @Shoaeb no either

Comment: are you waiting for 28800000 ??

Comment: you could add 
System.out.println(new Date());
response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
System.out.println(new Date());

Comment: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler.html#retryRequest(java.io.IOException,%20int,%20org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext). Doesnt the execurionCount in retryRequest() helps